# New Itunes connect Sep 2014 submission stuck at "Submit for Review" page

Tags: app-store-connect, freeze

After I click Submit for Review
Itunes Connect bring me to this page and when I click Submit
It's stuck forever...

[image]

Update : 14 Sep 2014
now it does not stuck but become this

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the build you selected is not inactive. Once you upload your build you have to immediately choose it and submit it to the App Store. Otherwise, the build will become inactive and you won't be able to submit it. Make sure to change the build number before reuploading to avoid the redundant build error message. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I try upload new build (v1.1) but still stuck at this page. It seem like itunesconnect server bug.

Comment: Yes you're right. It seems that the reason uploads were stuck at the submit page is because Apple's servers were just too busy. Now it's working fine.

Answer (score 1):

This does appear to be some sort of bug. Here's something that worked for me:

1. Go back into iTunes Connect -->  --> 'Versions', and delete the build from this submission. You need to make a new one, unfortunately
2. Go into Xcode, click on your project, then click on your target and go to the tab 'General'
3. Increment the 'Build' number. For example, I went from 1.0.0.0 to 1.0.0.1, but for you it might be going from 534 to 535. It doesn't matter, just as long as it's different
4. Go 'Product' --> 'Archive'. Ensure that you have selected a real iPhone device as the build target, as opposed to one of the simulators
5. Follow the process as you did before ('Window' --> 'Organizer' --> Distribute, etc.) and resubmit in iTunes Connect.

Good luck!